# How to add random input after inactivity time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a webpage and I want to make "type" effect on form. After user waits for a while, it starts typing some text as an example, if possible - with cursor. I don't really know where to start though. I'm using jQuery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I too don't know where to start with!!

Comment: @kosciak, you haven't shown any attempt to solve your own issue. Please do some research and include a [mcve] explaining exactly what you're struggling with. Otherwise this is a work order and should be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Animate the Placeholder

You might use the [placeholder attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) to display example input. Static text is usually enough for most users. Yet, you could add an animation loop to simulate typing. Using the placeholder also allows you to display text without altering the form input value.

The example below uses a loop to simulate typing and stops with the user enters information. No jQuery required.

**Run the snippet to demo**

```js
var timerId, placeholder = fullname.placeholder, n =0;

id = setInterval(function() {

  if (fullname.value) {
    // stop as user has typed something
    clearInterval(id);
    fullname.placeholder = placeholder;
   }
  else {
    // show next character
    fullname.placeholder = placeholder.substr(0,n);
    n = (n+1) % (placeholder.length+1);
  }
  
}, 400);
```

```css
input {font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive; font-size:36px; border:1px solid steelblue;color:black; font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<input id="fullname" placeholder="Berlin, Germany">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a timeout function at form load using settimeout function.

If user presses a key you can cancel it.

The timeout function callback could set the placeholder of your input using jQuery.

Consider the inserted snippet to have an idea on how to start a proper implementation.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var exampleText = "my example text";
  var inactivityDelay = 2000;
  var typeDelay = 200;
  var interval;

  var appendExample = function() {
    var index = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (index >= exampleText.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }

      var myinput = $("#myinput");
      myinput.attr("placeholder", myinput.attr("placeholder") + exampleText.charAt(index++));
    }, typeDelay);
  };

  var timeout = setTimeout(appendExample, inactivityDelay);

  $("#myinput").on("change paste keyup focus", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    clearInterval(interval);
    $("#myinput").attr("placeholder", "");
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="myinput" maxlength="100" placeholder="" />
</form>
```

Comment: above comment had the loop, so what I've needed exactly. but thank you anyway :)